# Trouble importing model from other app with Django

Tags: python, django, model, import

I'm in trouble trying to import a model from another app. I've two apps "main" and "administrative". Here the code, where I stripped out some verbose description :

"administrative" model:

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm


class Contract(models.Model):
    Code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Provider = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ActivationDate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    EndingDate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    Note = models.TextField(blank=True)
    Numbers = models.ManyToManyField('main.Number', through='Crefcontr2num')

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s %s' % (self.Provider, self.Description)

class Crefcontr2num(models.Model):
    Dateto = models.DateField()
    Datefrom = models.DateField()
    Contract = models.ForeignKey('Contract')
    Num = models.ForeignKey('main.Number')
```

"main" model:

```
from django.db import models
from endusers.models import OrderedEndUser
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea, TextInput, HiddenInput
#from administrative.models import Contract

class Device(models.Model):
    Maker = models.CharField(error_messages={'required': 'need !'})
    Model = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    Imei = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    Note = models.TextField(blank=True)
    ActiveState = models.BooleanField()
    AcquisitionDate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    DismissionDate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    CodInv = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    FK_Enduser = models.ForeignKey('endusers.OrderedEndUser',unique=False, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    #   FK_Contract = models.ForeignKey(administrative.Contract, unique=False, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

...please note ""#" up in import and in front of FK_Contract in model "device", if I simply try to import (without #) the model Contract, I've got this error :

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0xb6f69a6c>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 88, in inner_run
self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 249, in validate
num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 35, in get_validation_errors
for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 146, in get_app_errors
self._populate()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 61, in _populate
self.load_app(app_name, True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 78, in load_app
models = import_module('.models', app_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/media/truecrypt1/develope/Django-1.3.1/dbMobile/../dbMobile/main/models.py", line 5, in <module>
from administrative.models import Contract #, Crefcontr2num
File "/media/truecrypt1/develope/Django-1.3.1/dbMobile/administrative/models.py", line 28, in <module>
class ContractForm(ModelForm):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 205, in __new__
opts.exclude, opts.widgets, formfield_callback)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 159, in fields_for_model
formfield = f.formfield(**kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1155, in formfield
'queryset': self.rel.to._default_manager.using(db).complex_filter(self.rel.limit_choices_to)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_default_manager'
```

I look so far everywhere and tried many option.. but error is still there... I'm unable to understand...  I read about circular import etc... and tried referring with path (as you can see), but it doesn't work as well...

any advice is appreciated...
thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your traceback shows the error is with class `ContractForm` which you have defined in `administrative/models.py` on line 28

```
...
File "/media/truecrypt1/develope/Django-1.3.1/dbMobile/../dbMobile/main/models.py", line 5, in <module>
from administrative.models import Contract #, Crefcontr2num 
File "/media/truecrypt1/develope/Django-1.3.1/dbMobile/administrative/models.py", line 28, in <module> 
class ContractForm(ModelForm):
...
```

Since you haven't included that part of your code in your question, there's not much more i can tell you.
However you should be aware how importing in Python works. When you use

```
from administrative.models import Contract
```

Python does not just select that one class from the `administrative/models.py` file. Instead the Python interpreter reads the entire file, creates the module object, executes the code from the imported file in the new modules namespace, and then copies the name `Contract` from the new module's namespace to the current namespace. So, although it seems that you are importing just one class from a module, an error **anywhere** in that module can prevent a successful import - in your case it is an error with class `ContractForm`. The rest of the traceback details what exactly went wrong with that class.

Comment: thx Michał Modzelewski... you've shooted the problem...  unluckly in the middle of my path I faced two or more problems... and I missed the focus on that ! It seem the problem was in a many to many field...  thx again to have me routed to tha right problem, and remembered well on import concept...

Answer (score 1):

If i am not wrong .If you are importing the Contract model and its seems that those two apps are kept in apps folder so you have to add apps while importing

```
from apps.administrative.models import Contract
```

you should use this model directly like bellow

```
FK_Contract = models.ForeignKey(Contract, unique=False, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Comment: yes, but... if I trie in that way, I get this error :  "    FK_Contract = models.ForeignKey(Contract, unique=False, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
NameError: name 'Contract' is not defined"

Comment: ..so if I try to import Contract I have to import the object model Contract (note without quote), nevertheless if I try explicit the key directly with the path 'administrative.Contract'  I get same error as posted...

Comment: @Alessio Tomelleri I am updating answer

Comment: I have the folder project "dbMobile", and its inside subfolders for every apps as: "administrative" and "main" ...for each of them I have inside: models.py e view.py ...

Comment: preceding an import statement with the project name is a bad and unnecessary practice. Python apps are made to be reusable. If you do this then you can't install the app anyweree else without editing all imports.

Answer (score -1):

I just hope that the indentation problems in the code you posted in this question are not acctually happpening in your real code.

For example, your `administrative/models.py` should look like this:

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    Code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Provider = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ActivationDate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    EndingDate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    Note = models.TextField(blank=True)
    Numbers = models.ManyToManyField('main.Number', through='Crefcontr2num')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.Provider, self.Description)

class Crefcontr2num(models.Model):
    Dateto = models.DateField()
    Datefrom = models.DateField()
    Contract = models.ForeignKey('Contract')
    Num = models.ForeignKey('main.Number')
```

Some tips:

1. DO NOT name your model fields capitalized. Python's best practice is `date_to`, `date_from`, `contract`, and so on. Check [PEP 8 for details](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).
2. It's also a bad practice to preceed ForeignKey field with "FK_". Just redundant. Of course this is just my opinion. Maybe you are using some naming standard.... But if you could avoid this, it would be better.
3. Add the `verbose_name` param to your field definitions.
4. Add `default` values for `null=True, blank=True` fields.
5. Be verbose (give meaningful names) to your models. `Crefcontr2num` is a bad one.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes Francisco u are right in your advices, I have to keep in mind thats...  I'm bit worried if try some modify now in the middle... but for sure I focused them... thx

Comment: So, the problem was not indentation? What was it?

Comment: no no... not was identation, I wish it was :) ...at the end, as Michal focused it was due another modelform present in same models.py. I was right using 'path.name' referring it, but I lost my focus about the modelforms also present, where it has a foreignkey inside that refer to the model, which has to be imported...

Comment: pls, clarify me this last one "..If you do this *then* you can't install the app anyweree else without editing all imports"  to be precise, for first I say I use 'appname.model' and not 'project.appname.model' format, having clarify it.. so this is the reason 'cause I'm unable now to "remove" import statement about an app now ?! Is that beacuse I started at first importing the app.. and now I can't remove without error ?!? It seem a bit odd to me !? I think I would be able to change the format also after..  removing import statement and using explicit form 'appname.model' <continue>

Comment: <below from previous> ... actually I have to say it is what happen about app.model 'endousers.enduser' I'm unable to remove import statement now without face the error, also if I use 'appname.model' in place the object... but this is very strange to me...

Comment: I said that because of @Sashi answer. He suggested that.